# Why does core web vitals not correlate with Google PSI?

Tags: psi

Testing a domain in Google PSI shows 98% on mobile/desktop for all URLs.
But in Google WMT - It shows 7% are GOOD and the rest "NEED IMPROVEMENT".
Is there any accurate testing tool for this so we can find the problems and get 100% GOOD URLS ?

Comment: In other words - I test many URLs in PSI and they show 98% .. but according to WMT they aren't "GOOD" ... and I cannot find any tool which shows why.

Answer (score 0):

The score at the top of Google PSI is the [Lighthouse score](https://web.dev/performance-scoring/). The Lighthouse score does not indicate whether a page passes Core Web Vitals. To see whether a page passes Core Web Vitals, look at the "Field Data" section of the PSI report.

Comment: I see the Field Data but it does not say how to fix .. PSI gives 98% resuts all green for all URLS but then says it fails field data ... conflicting information.